# Get records by dates which present and not present

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

**Table**:

```
create table dttest
(
    names varchar(20),
    coldate datetime
);
```

**Records**:

```
insert into dttest values('A','2019-10-31');
insert into dttest values('A','2019-10-30');
insert into dttest values('A','2019-10-29');
insert into dttest values('B','2019-10-14');
insert into dttest values('B','2019-10-22');
```

**Query**: I am trying to get only those records which are **present in specific dates and not present in some dates**.

Try 1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dttest 
WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(coldate as DATE),105) NOT IN ('31-10-2019','22-10-2019')) AND 
      (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(coldate as DATE),105) IN ('14-10-2019'))
```

Output:

```
names       coldate
------------------------------
B           2019-10-14 00:00:00.000
```

`B` should not come because it is also present in `22-10-2019`, Expected output is NULL.

Try 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dttest t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM dttest t1 
    WHERE t.names = t1.names  
    AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(t1.coldate as DATE),105) NOT IN ('31-10-2019','30-10-2019'))
) AND
EXISTS
( 
    SELECT 1 FROM dttest t2 
    WHERE t.names = t2.names
    AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(t2.coldate as DATE),105) IN ('14-10-2019')) 
 )
```

No result but the expected output is `B`.

Comment: in your Query 1, you have the not in date `'22-10-2010` but `B` is `'22-10-2019`, so the query is correct

Comment: My bad, Typo! its `22-10-2019`.

Comment: You don't need to convert `coldate` to string for comparison since it does not contain the time component. This is sufficient :`WHERE coldate IN ('2019-10-14')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a double negative condition (`NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN`) on your second query. So the following query should get the expected result:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT names
FROM dttest 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM dttest t1 
  WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(coldate as DATE), 105) IN ('31-10-2019','30-10-2019') 
    AND t1.names = dttest.names
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM dttest t1 
  WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(coldate as DATE), 105) IN ('14-10-2019')
    AND t1.names = dttest.names
)
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=67838a292d378635c4d8e67ed8a86c65)